# Cartesian and strictly associative Path Object.

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Is there a path object functor $\mathrm{P}:\mathbf{Top}\rightarrow \mathbf{Top}$, with fibration $ev_{0},ev_{1}: \mathrm{P}(X)\rightarrow X\times X$ such that:

(1) $\mathrm{P}$ is a cartesian functor i.e., $\mathrm{P}(X\times Y)$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{P}(X)\times \mathrm{P}(Y).$

(2) and the concatenation map $-\ast-:\mathrm{P}(X)\times_{X}\mathrm{P}(X)\rightarrow \mathrm{P}(X)$ is strictly associative.

The condition (1) (but not (2)) is verified by the standard path object $\mathrm{P}(-)= \mathrm{Map}([0,1],-)$
and the condition (2) (but not (1)) is verified by the moore path object $\mathrm{M}(-)$ which is not a cartesian functor.

Comment: Sure: let $P = \text{Hom}(\{0, 1 \}, -)$. 

Comment: That is not a path object! Just to be clear a path object $\mathrm{P}(X)$ factors the diagonal $\Delta: X\rightarrow X\times X$ to $X\rightarrow \mathrm{P}(X)\rightarrow X\times X$ where the first map is a weak equivalence and the second is a fibration. 

Comment: I have undeleted this question which you have deleted six years ago. -- Please do not self-delete your useful questions!